# MySQL Dynamic Pivot Table not giving proper results

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm somewhat of a SQL rookie but I'm trying to write a pivot between three tables. I have the below query and it works perfectly aside from the MAX call. It causes my values that are less than the default value to be overridden. I have screenshots of my tables below. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(cc.company_config_key_id  = ', cck.id, ', cc.config_value, \'', cck.default, '\')) AS ', cck.company_config_key
        )
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM company_config cc
    LEFT JOIN company_config_key cck
    ON cck.id = cc.company_config_key_id;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT co.id, co.name, ', @sql, ' FROM companies co LEFT JOIN company_config cc ON cc.company_id = co.id GROUP BY co.id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

companies:

[image: Companies table]

company_config_key:

[image: company_config_key table]

company_config:

[image: company_config table]

Result (the secondary colors for companies 1 and 2 should be set):

[image: query result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had to set the internal if statement to NULL and then wrapped the max statement in an IFNULL.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('IFNULL(MAX(IF(cc.company_config_key_id  = ', cck.id, ', cc.config_value, NULL)), \'', cck.default, '\') AS ',cck.company_config_key)
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM company_config cc
    LEFT JOIN company_config_key cck
    ON cck.id = cc.company_config_key_id;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT co.id, co.name, ', @sql, ' FROM companies co LEFT JOIN company_config cc ON cc.company_id = co.id GROUP BY co.id');
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```